# Area Code Separate Field

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

Should I have area code stored in a separate field in my DB? It's causing me a lot of pain in terms of parsing user input...but it would add value to have it searchable....but I'm not sure how much.

Right now we have the structure

- CountryCode
- AreaCode
- ExchangeAndSuffix
- Extension

We're considering combining AreaCode and ExchangeAndSuffix.

What's the standard practice here?

Thanks.

Comment: Does every country have an area code?

Comment: "Most cases" means every country doesn't use area codes. The ones that do use a varying number of digits.

Comment: And many countries change their phone structure over time. For example Greece, changed from having Area codes to not having a few years ago.

Comment: so are you suggesting we combine areacode and exchangeandsuffix into something like "Number"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you have to answer is this: "Does a phone number represent a singular value, or does it represent several values who combine to form a singular tuple?" In other words, do you have actual logic (be it querying or business logic) that is dictated by these components (area code, exchange, etc.), or is a phone number just a phone number?

Comment: We definitely have a reporting desire to be able to find area codes...but there's ways of doing things like looking for the first three digits to accomplish that....

Comment: If the area code represents something specific to you, then it should be in its own field.